# If $a,b,c,d$ are solutions to the equation $x^4-bx-3=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $a,b,c,d$ are solutions to the equation $$x^4-bx-3=0$$ then the equation whose solutions are $$\frac{a+b+c}{d^2},\frac{a+b+d}{c^2},\frac{a+c+d}{b^2},\frac{b+c+d}{a^2}$$ has the form
>
> A) $x^4-3bx+1=0$
>
> B) $3x^4-bx^3-1=0$
>
> C) $3x^4+bx^3-1=0$
>
> D) $3x^4-bx+1=0$
>
> E) $3x^4+bx+1=0$
>
> F) There's no right answer

Can somebody help me with this problem, let me know if my translation is too bad to understand

Comment: Would you mind typing the question up in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? Images are hard to search for and they aren't accessible to people who are blind and use screen readers.

Comment: I have typedup your question using MathJax. Please read [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn more about it

Comment: Please also add some details about what you have already tried when solving this problem - people will be more willing to help if they can see you have put in some effort yourself first

Answer (score 3):

In this case $a+b+c+d=0$ so we can write $\dfrac {a+b+c}{d^2}$ as $\dfrac {a+b+c+d-d}{d^2}$ which is $\dfrac {-1}{d}$, So now we need to find eqn whose roots are $\dfrac {-1}{a}$, $\dfrac {-1}{b}$, $\dfrac {-1}{c}$ and$\dfrac {-1}{d}$.

Comment: Thank you. well done. +1

Comment: Thanks @Qurultay for the edit

Answer (score 0):

By Vieta's formula

$a+b+c+d=0$

You have to find an equation with roots

${a+b+c+d-x \over x^2}$ where $x=a,b,c,d$

$-1/a,-1/b,-1/c,-1/d$

So substitute $y=-1/x $